# Select меняет содержимое

Tags: javascript, select

Делаю так:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
  var shouts = {
    1: "Day",
    2: "Day",
    3: "Day",
    4: "Week",
    5: "Week"

  };

  function shoutbox(select) {
    var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

    if (selected.value in shouts) {

      document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = shouts[selected.value];
    } else {

      document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Day";
    }
  }
</script>

    <select id="calc" class="calc_cell" onchange="shoutbox(this); func(this)">
                    <option selected value="1">Day</option>
                    <option value="2">Day</option>
                    <option value="3">Day</option>
                    <option value="4">Week</option>
                    <option value="5">Week</option>
                </select>
```

Работает только когда делаешь выбор в селект, а при загрузке страницы в div пусто, как заставить отображаться сразу же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После объявления функции её нужно вызывать ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpe4L9ur/)):

```
function shoutbox(select) {
    var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

    if (selected.value in shouts) {

        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = shouts[selected.value];
    } else {

        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Day";
    }
}

shoutbox(document.getElementById("calc"));
```

Вызов функции необходимо осуществлять после блока `select` или на событии `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Это не будет работать, если просто добавить вызов функции в конец блока script.

Comment: Почему не будет работать? Правда лучше сделать вызов после кода select.

Comment: Да, данный код должен быть после блока select. Не обратил внимания, что в jsFiddle он ставится после всего HTML.

Comment: По порядок не учел, вставлял код вначале страницы.. и он как следствие не работал, как только поместил вниз страницы, все заработало! Спасибо огромное!